# Correct this Rails/ruby method for me, please?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I've a post model with act-as-taggable-on gem. Both tables have timestamps.

I started with

```
def tags
  @posts = current_user.posts.find_tagged_with(params[:tag], :order => "@posts.tags.updated_at DESC"])
end
```

And when that didn't work, I tried changing things and ended up with this mess.

```
def tags
  @posts = current_user.posts.find_tagged_with(params[:tag])
  @tags = @posts.tags.all
  @posts = @tags(params[:tag, :order => "@posts.tags.updated_at DESC"])
end
```

I basically want to sort by when the tags was last updated.

Bonus: Sort by tag.updated_at or post.updated_at, but in this particular app, I'll be updating tags the most, so just first one will be fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to join the `tags` table in your `find` statement:

```
def tags
  @posts = Post.find_tagged_with(
    params[:tag], 
    :conditions => {:user_id => current_user.id}, 
    :joins => :tags, 
    :order => 'tags.updated_at DESC',
    :group => 'posts.id'
  )
end
```

Note: Find the right conditions to select only posts from the current user. This example could work, though.

Comment: I'm afraid not. It still sorts by Post.updated_at. I want it to sort by Tag.updated_by. However if fetches only post from current_user.

Comment: Sry i misunderstood the question. The edited version should do it.

Comment: Hmm...still nothing and worse, it shows same results 4 times. I changed DESC to ASC and still the same order. I'm using this http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on for tags if that helps.

Comment: Ah, allright, you need to group the results of the join operation since there are obviously more than one tags on a post. I edited again to reflect this. No idea on the ordering issue, though.